# Resolving a namespace issue in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, namespaces, global-namespace

I have a module in my Rails app `Constants`, which has a few constants defined within itself. I recently included the mongo gem in my rails app and now all references to those constants throws an error.

> uninitialized constant Mongo::Constants::MY_FAVORITE_CONSTANT

The code is roughly as follows:

```
class Hello
  def self.world
    Constants::MY_FAVORITE_CONSTANT
  end
end
```

Now I tried changing the line in the above code to `::Constants::MY_FAVORITE_CONSTANT` but that results in the same error.

The module `Constants` resides in `app/models/constants.rb`.

Any help here would really be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Looks there is en-build Constants model in Mongo gem. Can you change your constants model name and give a try.

Comment: That was the last thing I wanted to try.. Is there anything else?

Comment: No, I suggested as per Error "uninitialized constant Mongo::Constants"